# Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.junit.internal.runners.TestClassRunner

Tags: junit, mockito, powermock

That class is not in my classpath.  Why is junit trying to load it?

Comment: Maybe the full stack will help us to understand the issue.

Answer (score 0):

TestClassRunner is the class required by jUnit/Mockito to prepare the classes for executing the test cases on them.

This error is very common and is caused by either the wrong version of `jUnit/Mockito` jar in build path, or either by wrong import of Mockito Classes.

Hope it helps!
Good luck